# How to name object keys on a loop in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to loop to do something like this

```
const firstColumn = {};

for (let index = 1; index < 20; index++) {
    firstColumn[index] = {}
}
```

I want to end with something like this

```
const data = {
    "1": {},
    "2": {},
    "3": {},
    // So on
}
```

But I'm getting this console output.

```
    Object {
  "1": Object {},
  "10": Object {},
  "11": Object {},
  "12": Object {},
  "13": Object {},
  "14": Object {},
  "15": Object {},
  "16": Object {},
  "17": Object {},
  "18": Object {},
  "19": Object {},
  "2": Object {},
  "3": Object {},
  "4": Object {},
  "5": Object {},
  "6": Object {},
  "7": Object {},
  "8": Object {},
  "9": Object {},
}
```

the Funny thing if I limit the loop iteration to less than 10 I get the right sequence.

```
for (let index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
    firstColumn[index] = {}
}
```

// output

```
Object {
"1": Object {},
  "2": Object {},
  "3": Object {},
  "4": Object {},
  "5": Object {},
  "6": Object {},
  "7": Object {},
  "8": Object {},
  "9": Object {},
}
```

I honestly don't get it. Maybe somebody smarter than me can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the keys sorted? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: An array of objects may be better in this case, instead of an object with sequential keys of more objects.

Comment: Yeah but I have a third part module that thanks those that format for some odd reason. If it was an array it would have being pretty straight forward.

Comment: Because keys are STRINGS, not numbers.  Not all JS engines honor order by how they were entered.

Comment: @epascarello and according to the spec, string keys are ordered by insertion time, not lexically.

Comment: What a nutty requirement for that 3rd party module. Fork it and change it to something sane.

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, but not all engines work that way, hence why people always have said not to rely on order of an object.

Comment: Where are you printing that output? You are seeing the ordering your engine / console chose to represent objects. Object key-value pairs are not sorted, as long as you don't iterate over them with a `for..in` et al.

Comment: The console is free to output object properties in any order it choses to use.

Comment: The output its just a console.log(firstColumn) at the end of the code

Comment: Also, the order that the console uses is no guarantee at all of what a third party API will determine as the order.